# WSL2 not starting after wsl --shutdown

Tags: windows, shutdown, windows-subsystem-for-linux, reboot

I had a problem with my Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 11. It kept lagging to the point where I couldn't do anything. So, I ran 'wsl --shutdown'. Then tried to restart it with the "Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service" command. However it refuses to turn back on. When I opened "Ubuntu on Windows" from microsoft store - it opens a blank terminal. Any wsl commands in cmd or PowerShell terminal ( with admin rights ) take forever to return something. I restarted my PC, just to see if it could help - but nothing.

I need Ubuntu for work, can someone please help? I tried to figure it out on my own, but I'm pretty new to WSL/Ubuntu overall and I'm unable to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @David i'm using the 20.04 version with WSL2

Comment: Try running `wsl -l -v` from PowerShell.  Does that return anything?

Comment: Also, what Windows version and WSL version?  On some recent releases, the `LxssManager` service isn't used at all.  Starting it may have caused the problem, but not sure.  Really, though, there's been no need that I'm aware of to restart the Service in many, many years.  WSL should restart automatically after a `wsl --shutdown` just by running `wsl`.